# MOSS 2007: Multi-layer flyout menus on the global navigation

Tags: sharepoint-designer, client-object-model, master-page, navigation

I've reset the MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels to 30. My goal is to create a global navigation menu that leads to other SharePoint sites/external links. Each tab on the navigation is the top category with sub categories that ultimately lead to pages/external links. While this is relatively easy to create on your standard webpage, I am having issues creating a dynamic menu that can be easily changed by admins as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Created a site heirarchy. Basically, under the top level, I created sub-sites. Under each subsite, I added the links I needed. The top level site displayed sites and their navigation in the flyout. Changed `MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels` to 5 because no more than 5 were needed.

Comment: Is this an answer to the question posed by the OP?

Comment: It was, I just wasn't logged in. :)